# Grails: Splitting a string that contains a pipe

Tags: java, regex, grails, groovy, split

I’m trying to split a `String`. Simple examples work:

```
groovy:000> print "abc,def".split(",");
[abc, def]===> null
groovy:000>
```

But instead of a comma, I need to split it on pipes, and I’m not getting the desired result:

```
groovy:000> print "abc|def".split("|");
[, a, b, c, |, d, e, f]===> null
groovy:000>
```

So of course my first choice would be to switch from pipes (`|`) to commas (`,`) as delimiters.

But now I’m intrigued: Why is this not working? Escaping the pipe (`\|`) doesn't seem to help:

```
groovy:000> print "abc|def".split("\|");
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, groovysh_parse: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 24.
   print "abcdef".split("\|");
                          ^

1 error
|
        at java_lang_Runnable$run.call (Unknown Source)
groovy:000>
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to split on `\\|`.

Comment: Could you provide an example? Isn't it the same as the last code snippet I provided?

Comment: @Tom, it was a formatting problem, he meant `\\|`. You need to escape the `\ ` in order to have it interpreted in the String, so it can escape the `|`

Comment: @Colin Thank you very much. Didn't catch that formatting problem. My apologies.

Comment: Why `|` sign only have a problem of formatting? others are working properly. @Tom

Answer (score 24):

You have to escape pipe as, indeed, it has a special meaning in the regular expression. However, if you use quotes, you have to escape the slash as well. Basically, two options then:

```
asserts "abc|def".split("\\|") == ['abc','def']
```

or using the `/` as string delimiter to avoid extra escapes

```
asserts "abc|def".split(/\|/) == ['abc','def']
```

Comment: Thanks! The `/` seems perly and familiar :)

Comment: +1 for the explanation and the correctly-formatted demonstration.  I don't know why the other answer is getting all the love, this one's much better.