# Split a text twice with Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I would like to split this text contact into 3 parts separated by `-`.

In each part we have: name, function, number and email.

Then I'd like to separate each part by `\n`.

```
def contact = '''name1
Function1
: 1111
: name1@mail.com-name2 
Function2
: 2222
: name2@mail.com-name3
Function3
: 3333
: name3@mail.com
'''
```

I've tried this:

```
def contact_part = contact.split('-')
println contact_part[0]
def data = contact_part.split('\n') //line 15
println data[1]
```

But I got this error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.split() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [
>   ]
>   Possible solutions: split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), sort(), init(), tail(), toList()
>       at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:15)

Thank you.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450680/splitting-string-with-delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this exception, because you have called `.split()` on `String[]`. The first split creates an array of strings, so the next split has to be applied on each element of this array. Consider following example:

```
def contact = '''name1
Function1
: 1111
: name1@mail.com-name2 
Function2
: 2222
: name2@mail.com-name3
Function3
: 3333
: name3@mail.com
'''

contact.split('-').each { part ->
    def data = part.split('\n').toList()

    println "name: ${data[0]}, function: ${data[1]}, number: ${data[2].replace(': ', '')}, email: ${data[3].replace(': ', '')}"
}
```

We split input string by `-` and then each part got split by `\n`. For each split part we print console output like:

```
name: name1, function: Function1, number: 1111, email: name1@mail.com
name: name2 , function: Function2, number: 2222, email: name2@mail.com
name: name3, function: Function3, number: 3333, email: name3@mail.com
```

Note that I've added `.replace(': ', '')` to clean number and email values.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well.
Please, if "name" is a sentence with two word separated by space " ", like this:"lastname firstname"
How can I get the lastname, and the firstname?

Comment: That's okey, I solved the second problem.

Since "${data[0]}" is a string, so I can apply the split method:

def lastname = "${data[0]}".split(' ')[0]

def firstname = "${data[0]}".split(' ')[1]

println lastname

println firstname